# Trying to figure out the logic in my Connect Four game in Python

Tags: python

I'm a fairly new to Python and I'm working on a Connect Four game. I'm able to initialize the board, make moves myself, and make the computer move. However, I know that there must be a better way of "placing my pieces" than the huge nest of IF statements that I have. Furthermore, I'm not sure how to approach the logic of actually checking whether or not the game has been "won" or drawn.

Here's my code:

```
import random

board = [["." for x in range(7)] for x in range(6)]
symbol = ""

def boardLogic(pick, user):
    if user == "user":
        symbol = "0"
    else:
        symbol = "X"
    if board[0][pick] != ".":
        if board[1][pick] != ".":
            if board[2][pick] != ".":
                if board[3][pick] != ".":
                    if board[4][pick] != ".":
                        if board[5][pick] != ".":
                            if board[6][pick] != ".":
                                print("That column is full.")
                            else:
                                board[6][pick] = symbol
                        else:
                            board[5][pick] = symbol
                    else:
                        board[4][pick] = symbol
                else:
                    board[3][pick] = symbol
            else:
                board[2][pick] = symbol
        else:
            board[1][pick] = symbol
    else:
        board[0][pick] = symbol

def printBoard():
    for row in board:
        for val in row:
            print '{:4}'.format(val),
        print

won = False
while not won:
    printBoard()

    #pick a column
    #ADD FUNCTIONALITY TO DISALLOW A FULL COLUMN FROM BEING ENTERED
    while True:
        try:
            yourPick = int(raw_input('Pick a column 0 - 6: '))
        except ValueError: # just catch the exceptions you know!
            print 'That\'s not a number!'
        else:
            if 0 <= yourPick < 6: # this is faster
                break
            else:
                print 'Out of range. Try again'
    print(yourPick)
    #column logic
    boardLogic(yourPick, "user")

    #opponent randomly picks a column
    theirPick = random.randint(0, 6)
    print(theirPick)
    #column logic
    boardLogic(theirPick, "notUser")

    #check win conditions
    #won = True
```

Comment: You might want to check out [stackoverflow's codeview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just a tip, there is a working implementation of the game here: https://github.com/reutsharabani/connect4  (not perfect in any way, but it even has a very good AI player). Disclaimer: I wrote it. You'll be interested in the logic part: https://github.com/reutsharabani/connect4/blob/master/connect4/logic/game.py

Comment: `index = min([-1] + [i for i in range(len(board)) if board[pick] == "."])`    `if index == -1: print("That column is full.")`    `else: board[i][pick] = symbol`

Comment: @ReutSharabani Thanks, but a lot of that goes way over my head at my current skill level. Are there docs or an explanation anywhere?

Comment: @AKor not currently, this was just to practice some python. But the basic functions are pretty small (like the win condition...). I tried to name things properly. Naming things is known to be a hard problem.